# bash script: sudo no interactive echo redirection to a file

Tags: bash, sudo

in a bash script I'm trying to redirect a text printed with echo with sudo non interactive  to a file. But I'm not clear about how to do it.

I tried with this code:

```
echo $sudopass| sudo -S echo "user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" >     /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
```

Comment: Is your question about permissions? You ought to mention the actual error that you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Output redirection is not affected by elevated `sudo` permissions. The part that you `sudo` is the `echo`, *not* the redirection of that command's output.

That will still happen with your current user's permission.

So you need a way to append a line to a file that does not involve output redirection.

---

**Note:** *Earlier version of this answer showcasing `sed` removed as `sed` balks if the target file is empty or non-existing. As I wanted to keep the gist of the answer intact -- "how to avoid output redirection" -- I added instructions on how to use `vi` for the same purpose.*

---

Every POSIX-compliant system needs to have the `vi` / `ex` editor. (On contemporary Linux machines usually a link starting Vim in compatiblity mode.) You can "remote-control" ex / vi / Vim through the command line:

```
vi -es -c "normal! G" -c "normal! ouser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" -c "x" /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
```

(This is without the `sudo` part for clarity.)

Explanation:

- `-e` starts `vi` in "ex mode". (Equivalent to calling `ex`.)
- `-s` means "silent" -- no prompts, no messages.
- `-c` passes a command to the editor to be executed once the first file has been read.
- `"normal! G"` first puts the editor in "normal mode" -- that is what you would find yourself in if you started `vi` interactively; `ex` is in "command mode" by default (as if you entered `:` in vi). The `G` moves the cursor to the last line.
- `"normal! o..."` again activates normal mode, adds a line after the current line, and activates "insert mode". The rest of the string is entered verbatim.
- `"x"` saves the file and exits the editor.

The command line including the `sudo` part:

```
echo $sudopass | sudo -S vi -es -c "normal! G" -c "normal! ouser ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD:ALL" -c "x" /etc/sudoers.d/ansible
```

Comment: I forget tell that file "/etc/sudoers.d/ansible" is  empty and this sed commad needs any content to append the new text. I found this order to use the redirection with sudo but I not sure if is the best idea call a sh comand with sudo inside the script or if is any other more elegant way to insert some code in a empty file with sudo non interactive:  ->  sudo -S sh -c 'echo "#ANSIBLE entry > /etc/sudoers.d/ansible"'

Comment: @jhd00023: Yes, `sed` acts up if the target file has no previous contents. I changed the answer to use `vi` instead (to keep true to its original "don't use redirections with `sudo`" message). Your way of passing the whole command *including* redirection to `sh -c` works as well, of course.

Comment: Shoutout to @Rich for helping me with [the fine print of proper command-line `vi` usage](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/12772/1726) over at vi.stackexchange.com.